# minimum_height doesn't work in a Layout inside .py (only work in .kv)?

Tags: kivy

I've tried to make a program that uses a scroll, I tried with RecycleView

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rc = RecycleView()
        box = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint_y=None)
        b1 = Button(text="1", size_hint_y=None, height=500)
        b2 = Button(text="2", size_hint_y=None, height=500)
        b3 = Button(text="3", size_hint_y=None, height=500)
        box.add_widget(b1)
        box.add_widget(b2)
        box.add_widget(b3)
        box.height = box.minimum_height
        rc.add_widget(box)
        return rc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I was expected that I was able to use the scroll, but the minimum_height seems that is always 0, and I don't want to give the exact height number by hand.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind `minimum_height` to the `height` using `setter` as follow:

```
box.bind(minimum_height=box.setter('height'))
```

## Snippets - py file

```
def build(self):
    rc = RecycleView()
    box = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint_y=None)
    ...
    box.bind(minimum_height=box.setter('height'))
    rc.add_widget(box)
    return rc
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)